# How does the flip function work?

Tags: haskell

Haskell newbie here. I was going through Learn you a haskell, and came across this definition of the flip function.

```
flip' :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)  
flip' f = g  
    where g x y = f y x
```

What I don't get is, where did x and y come from? I mean, the signature tells me that `flip'` is a function that takes a function (with two parameters), and returns a function (again, with two parameters).

If I'm understanding this right, when I write a function which goes like

```
foo :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
foo f x = f x   -- applies the function f on x
```

But then, in this case I'm passing the parameter explicitly [ ie `x` ] and so I'm able to access it in the function body. So how come the `flip'` function can access the parameters x and y?

Comment: Do you know that `(a -> b) -> a -> b` and `(a -> b) -> (a -> b)` are equivalent?

Comment: Equivalent because -> operator associates to the right? Similar to how  I can write `a -> (b -> c)` as `a -> b -> c`.

Comment: Exactly. I thought it would help to see that `foo f x = f x` is the same as `foo f = f` (given the same type signature). Anyway, those parameters `x` and `y` you mention are bound in the definition of `g`, that's where they come from. The definition of `g` can also be written as `g = (\x y -> f y x)`. This means that `flip'` could also be defined as `flip' f = (\x y -> f y x)`, which is equivalent to `flip' f x y = f y x`. This is in a way related to the right-associativity of `(->)`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The [Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Prelude.html), which is in the [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base) package at hackage.haskell.org, is included with an implicit import in every Haskell file is where the [flip](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:flip) function is found.  On the right side you can click "source" and see the [source code for flip](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#flip).

```
flip         :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y   =  f y x
```

The where clause allows for local definitions, `x=10` or `y="bla"`. You can also define functions locally with the same syntax you would for the top level. `add x y = x + y`

In the below equivalent formulation I make the substitution `g = f y x`

```
flip         :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y   =  g
  where
    g = f y x
```

Right now g takes no parameters. But what if we defined g as `g a b = f b a` well then we would have:

```
flip         :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f x y   =  g x y
  where
    g a b = f b a
```

No we can do a little algebraic cancelation(if you think of it like algebra from math class you will be pretty safe).  Focusing in on:

```
flip f x y   =  g x y
```

Cancel the y on each side for:

```
flip f x   =  g x
```

Now cancel the x:

```
flip f   =  g
```

and now to put it back in the full expression:

```
flip     :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f   =  g
  where
    g a b = f b a
```

As a last cosmetic step we can make the substitution `a` to `x` and `b` to `y` to recover the function down to argument names:

```
flip     :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
flip f   =  g
  where
    g x y = f y x
```

As you can see this definition of flip is a little round about and what we start with in the prelude is simple and is the definition I prefer. Hope that helps explain how `where` works and how to do a little algebraic manipulation of Haskell code.

Comment: My last edit was so I did not shadow any names n my g definition, hopefully that will make it clearer for those not used to how scoping works yet in Haskell.

Comment: One small comment: when you do the 'cancellation', I believe the type for `flip` should also change. Like: `flip f x   =  g x` should have type `flip     :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> (a -> c)`. Thus `flip f   =  g` should have type `flip     :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`.

Comment: @Lingxiao - One way to check this is put both into ghci and see what ghc tells you, it should give you the same signature modulo labels.  Another method is to use the right associative property of `(->)`. Meaning `f :: b -> a -> c` is equivalent to `f :: b -> (a -> c)` is equivalent to `f::(b -> (a -> c)` is equivalent to `f::(a -> b -> c)`.  This type of transformation can be used to show your first type sig. `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> (a -> c)` is equivalent to your second type sig. `flip :: (a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`.

Comment: `On the right side you can click "source" and see the source code for flip.` click somehwere in the terminal?  I looked it up on Hoogle but the definition seems wrong.  @Lingxiao, if flip takes a function and two arguments and reverses the arguments shouldn't it read `flip :: (a -> b- > c) -> (a -> c -> b)`?

Answer (score 17):

`flip'` doesn't access `x` and `y`. It receives an argument `f`, and evaluates to the expression `g`. No `x` or `y` in sight.

However, `g` is itself a function, defined with an auxiliary equation in the `where` clause of `flip'`.

You can read `g x y = f y x` exactly as if it were a top level equation like `flip'`. So `g` is a function of two arguments, `x` and `y`. It's `g` that has access to `x` and `y`, not `flip'`. Values for those arguments don't exist until `g` is applied, which is not until after `flip'` has returned the function `g` (if ever).

The thing that's special that about `g` being defined in the `where` clause of `flip'` is that it can have access to the arguments of `flip'`, which is how `g` can be defined in terms of `f`.

So when `flip'` is invoked it receives a function `f`. For each particular invocation of `flip'`, it constructs a new function `g`. `g` would receive two arguments, `x` and `y`, when it is called, but that hasn't happened yet. `flip'` then just returns `g` as its result.

Comment: Okay, I think things are getting less foggier. The way I see it - `g` is a kind of delegate (is that the right term? ) which will be evaluated when `flip'` gets called.

Comment: @ersran9 Not really. `g` is the return value of `flip'`. Someone who calls `flip'` gets the return value; it's up to them when (and if, and how many times) they call it. Like any return value, what is done with it afterwards has nothing to do with `flip'`.

Answer (score 2):

One simple example to understand and illustrate, on your ghci do:

```
Prelude> sub x y = x - y
Prelude> sub 3 1
2
Prelude> flip sub 3 1
-2
```

Comment: I don't think the question misunderstands what `flip` is used for, but how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find the type of `g`.

We know flip type : `(a -> b -> c) -> (b -> a -> c)`

Therefore we can deduce `f` type : `(a -> b -> c)`

We have this definition for `g`

```
g x y = f y x
```

From the right-hand-side we deduce that `y :: a` and `x :: b`.

Hence `g :: b -> a -> c`

Note that the definition could be rewritten without the 'where' clause.

```
flip' f = g where g x y = f y x
-> flip' f a b = g a b where g a b = f b a
-> flip' f a b = f b a
```

Comment: That barely answers the question. The question is about binding and using x and y.

Comment: I think the type analysis explains much of the definition. However, I edited to better address the question of the bindings, hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, you can also define functions in a *where* block. So the variables `x` and `y` are just the formal parameters of `g`, and that's why you can access it in `g x y = f y x`: `g x y` defines formal parameters `x` and `y`, and `f y x` is the definition of what `g` does. Finally, that definition is returned from `flip f = g`.